# PHP string replace load text file

Tags: php

well i know that how to replace string using PHP str_replace. I have code for multiple string replace it works fine

```
$subject = 'afsdfasdfasdfasd #%^#^%#@@';
$string = array('a','b','c','d','e','@','#','%','!');
echo str_replace($string, '', $subject);
```

i have put many words on text file one by one like

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
http://
stackoverflow.com
questions
ask
gfx
value
words
that
i want 
not
like
to
appear
in 
title
```

and named it 'replace.txt'
now my question is how i can load this text file for **string replace function** replace with empty

Comment: I would suggest by using phps file functions to open and read the lines, one by one, into an array. Or reading it at once and exploding the content afterwards into an array. What is the question here?

Comment: Do you want to use the values in replace.txt as the array you pass as the first parameter to str_replace?

Comment: Take a look at: [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: do you mean `file_get_content()` ?

Comment: yes ,  Terminus you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`$text = file_get_contents("replace.txt");`
`$terms = explode("\n", $text);`
`$string = "Hello World";`
`$string = str_replace($terms, '', $string);`
`echo($string);`

I edited this so replace.txt is the terms that are removed

Comment: Adrian Webster , good reply but  i want replace.txt into $string place

Comment: Replace.txt is in $text

Comment: I edited the answer, the original replace.txt is in $text and the replaced replace.txt is in $ntext

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you wanted, try the answer now :)

Comment: The terms in replace.txt seperated by newlines will be replaced with blank

Comment: In the general case, this approach will lead to wrong results. Take e.g. `$terms = array('in');` and `$text = "Wearing indigo jeans in summer"`. PHP's `str_replace()` strips *every* occurrence of the string `in`. This isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question isn't clearly stated, I suppose it's essentially this: You have a file with text (i.e. words separated by spaces) and you want to delete all words that occur in the list.

Assume `$text` contains the text to process, and `$terms` the lines like you posted above. Turn both into an array:

```
 $text = explode(' ', $text);
 $terms = explode("\n", $terms);
 $text = array_diff($text, $terms);
 $text = implode(' ', $text);
```

Of course you may need extra processing to get rid of punctuation and other stuff, but  `array_diff` is essentially what does the job.